# How to scale a set of different-sized images the same amount to fit one container?

Tags: css

I have multiple images of different sizes to display within one container. I want the images to all shrink the same percentage so that the widest one doesn't exceed the width of the container. For example:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="16x20.png" />
    <img src="16x40.png" />
    <img src="16x80.png" />
</div>
```

If the container is 80 pixels or wider, I want the images to all render at their original size.

If the container is 40 pixels wide, I would want the images to all be scaled down exactly 50% (that is, 8x10, 8x20, and 8x40). And so on.

I've tried a number of things including object-fit, max-width, transform: scale(); none of those seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: How is the width of the container being decided?

Comment: It's max 160px but could be less if the viewport is narrower.

Comment: So it's min(160px, 100vw)? I don't understand your convention on the image names, I would have expected the width to come first, but am I right in thinking the 16 is the height?

Comment: Yeah exactly, I flipped those by accident so 16 is the height in those examples.

Comment: Note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

From the way that you described it, I believe that you are looking for:

```
.container img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: scale-down;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

This will make the images responsive and fill the container for smaller sizes, but will not exceed 100% of their width for larger.

Comment: I don't want the images to each fill the whole container, but rather to maintain their proportional sizes to each other.

Answer (score 0):

I'll make the assumption that you can't alter the image's code and add IDs or classes, so I would suggest using the :nth-of-type selector.

```
.container img:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 25%;
}
.container img:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 50%;
}
.container img:nth-of-type(3) {
  width: 100%;
}
.container img {
  object-fit: scale-down;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

With that, you can select each image and give it a percentage of the container size.
See example to change container size:  https://codepen.io/doncroy/pen/OJomBzM